Why am i getting an error when i copy the micro xrce dds code into the arduino ide
the code of micro xrce dds isnt getting uploaded on the arduino ide
i tried to upload the code of micro xrce dds in the arduino ide but it is showing compilation error
the expected output was the built in led on the esp microcontroller board should start blinking
